# alarmManager doesn't run correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, alarm

I set a push alarm. But it doesn't work correctly.

Sometimes alarm pushes a few minutes later than I set up.

Moreover, it doesn't alarm me at all when I put 20 minutes later or something.

```
        private void setAlarm() {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("supplementsId", supplements.getSupplementsId());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode++, intent, 0);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }


    //[AlertReceiver.class]
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android:intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            id = intent.getLongExtra("supplementsId", -1);
            this.context = context;

            getSupplements();

            setNotification();
        }
    }

        private void setNotification() {
            NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context, supplements);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = 
            notificationHelper.getChannelNotification(supplements.getTitle(), "약 먹을 시간입니다.");
            notificationHelper.getManager().notify((int) supplements.getSupplementsId(), 
            notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the function you're using?

Comment: @ecm yes i did read

Comment: Your reply is addressed to the wrong user. I did not post that comment.

Comment: @dominicoder yes i did read

Comment: @byeongsu - do then did you notice that what you're seeing is expected behavior for an "inexact" alarm?

Comment: in the document, it says setInexactRepeating() is more recommended. I understand why it  alerts after few mins. But why doesn't it work after 30mins or more?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can solve by make the screen waking up.
If it can't solved refers to https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already refered to the official document. doesn't work. what do you mean that making the screen waking up?